# How to disable drag&drop for first Item of a ListView in QML

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML project where I am able to **drag & drop** rectangles that are in a `ListView`.
I want to **disable** the drag&drop feature for the **first Item** (rectangle) of the `ListView`.

Here is an example:

```
Rectangle {
    visible: true
    width: 1000; height: 1000
    ListView {
        id: root
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height

        model: DelegateModel {

            id: visualModel
            model: myModel
            model: ListModel {
                id: colorModel
                ListElement { someData }
                ...

            }

            delegate: MouseArea {

                property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

                id: delegateRoot
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                width: root.width; height: 100
                drag.target: icon
                drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
                drag.minimumY: 0
                property bool current: false

                Rectangle {
                  blablaData

                 //Something like : if firstItem, disable drag&drop
                }

                onClicked: {
                    delegateRoot.current = !delegateRoot.current;
                    if(current) {
                        delegateRoot.height = 300
                    }
                    else {
                        delegateRoot.height = 100
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                   id: container
                   anchors.top: icon.bottom
                   width: root.width-5
                   height: delegateRoot.height - icon.height
                   clip: true
                   border.color: "#81BEF7"
                   Behavior on implicitHeight {
                       PropertyAnimation { duration: 100 }
                   }
                   Text {
                       anchors.fill: parent
                       anchors.margins: 10
                       horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                       verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                       text: size
                   }
                 }

                DropArea {
                    anchors { fill: parent; margins: 15 }

                    onEntered: {                   
                          visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex)               
                    }
                 }
             }
          }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea of how to do it ? 
Thanks a lot !

EDIT: Added some features to my example

Answer (score 3):

In the delegate root item, try:

```
enabled: index ? true : false
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Your answer disables correctly the drag&drop for my first rectangle. 
But my rectangle has also some custom properties (onClicked etc) so if `enabled = false`, I can't click on it anymore. Any suggestion ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Once you imperatively set a property using javascript you lose the declarative functionality of QML. Can you please update your code with what you actually have written?

Comment: I just updated my code. In fact, I am doing an "accordion" item. So when I click on the rectangle, it will show a sub-menu (`Rectangle "container"` in my example).

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to do it, and you can use it for the item you want (not only the first one).

I need to change `drag.target` and `drag.axis` in `delegateRoot` by using and setting a boolean like `isDraggable` to `true` or `false` on each item and then use it like this:

```
drag.target: isDraggable ? content : undefined
drag.axis: isDraggable ? Drag.YAxis : Drag.None
```